# DynamicComponentLoader is not recognizing element created in runtime

Tags: angular

When trying to use DynamicComponentLoader

```
  this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(ComponentA,rootComponenetRef,'popupPlaceholder');
```

if the div with  #popupPlaceholder is inserted in runtime inside the html , the loader will not find the div.
Only if the div is written in compile time to the html the loader will recognize it.

How should I solve it?

Comment: can you show us some code of how you add the popupPlaceholder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's as designed. You can't add template variables at runtime, except as part of a components template where the component is added dynamically.